# Can't subset column despite columns are in dataframe

Tags: r, plot, group-by, subset, data-manipulation

I have this code:

```
    drugs_from_samples = read_excel("/Downloads/drugs from samples.xlsx") %>% 
       dplyr::select("drug", "Indication reviewed", "Action reviewed", "frequency")
```

which results in:
[image]

Then, when I try to

```
df = drugs_from_samples %>% 
  dplyr::select(-drug) %>% 
  group_by(`Indication reviewed`, `Action reviewed`) %>% 
  summarise(n = sum(frequency))


PieDonut(df,
         aes(df$`Indication reviewed`, df$`Action reviewed`, count = n))
```

When I try to plot the PieDonut, it gives me the error that:

> "Can't subset columns that don't exist. x Columns
> df$`Indicationreviewed` and df$`Actionreviewed`` don't
> exist"

I already looked for answers for this specific problems, can anybody give any help?

Comment: It is not recommended to have spaces in column names. It is difficult and confusing to use them. You may use `janitor::clean_names()` function to get better column names.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with the column names. Before performing the operations try this:

```
colnames(drugs_from_sample) <- gsub(" ", "_", colnames(drugs_from_sample))
```

This substitutes spaces with underscores in the column names. Then replace your code like:

```
df = drugs_from_samples %>% 
  dplyr::select(-drug) %>% 
  group_by(Indication_reviewed, Action_reviewed) %>% 
  summarise(n = sum(frequency))


PieDonut(df,
         aes(df$Indication_reviewed, df$Action_reviewed, count = n))
```

Comment: Still not working, it gives the same error as before

Comment: Instead of an image, it would be great if you could provide data with ```data.frame()``` or ```structure()``` so that we can reproduce your error